# LiveScript do closure not working

Tags: livescript

```
a = 5
do (a) ->
    console.log a
```

Why does this compile to

```
a = 5;
(function(a){
  return console.log(a);
})();
```

`a` is not passed in so it is undefined. Am I doing self executing closure wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LiveScript, `do` just invokes a function. You're looking for `let` :

```
let a
  console.log a
```